# Image grid fixed aspect ratio with dynamic size

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

```html
<div class="p-4">
  <div class="grid gap-4 sm:gap-8 grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 xl:grid-cols-6">
    <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41bffUhJ4xL._SL500_.jpg" />
    <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41bffUhJ4xL._SL500_.jpg" />
    <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41bffUhJ4xL._SL500_.jpg" />
    <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41bffUhJ4xL._SL500_.jpg" />
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612476464716-431a2751e006" />
  </div>
</div>
```

If I have a grid-like this, how can I force the images to have a 1:1 aspect ratio? Yes, I can use `object-cover`, but then I would need to set a fixed width/height. Is there a way to do this while still keeping the dynamic width?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need at least an extra container and apply the padding trick.

```css
.grid div {
  padding-top:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="p-4">
  <div class="grid gap-4 sm:gap-8 grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 xl:grid-cols-6">
    <div class="relative"><img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41bffUhJ4xL._SL500_.jpg" class="w-full h-full  absolute inset-0 object-cover"></div>
    <div class="relative"><img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41bffUhJ4xL._SL500_.jpg" class="w-full h-full  absolute inset-0 object-cover"></div>
    <div class="relative "><img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41bffUhJ4xL._SL500_.jpg" class="w-full h-full  absolute inset-0 object-cover"></div>
    <div class="relative"><img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41bffUhJ4xL._SL500_.jpg" class="w-full h-full  absolute inset-0 object-cover"></div>
    <div class="relative"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612476464716-431a2751e006" class="w-full h-full  absolute inset-0 object-cover"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also consider the following plugin: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-aspect-ratio to avoid writing any extra CSS and have a code like below

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="p-4">
  <div class="grid gap-4 sm:gap-8 grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 xl:grid-cols-6">
    <div class="relative aspect-h-1 aspect-w-1"><img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41bffUhJ4xL._SL500_.jpg" class="w-full h-full  absolute inset-0 object-cover"></div>
    <div class="relative aspect-h-1 aspect-w-1"><img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41bffUhJ4xL._SL500_.jpg" class="w-full h-full  absolute inset-0 object-cover"></div>
    <div class="relative aspect-h-1 aspect-w-1"><img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41bffUhJ4xL._SL500_.jpg" class="w-full h-full  absolute inset-0 object-cover"></div>
    <div class="relative aspect-h-1 aspect-w-1"><img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41bffUhJ4xL._SL500_.jpg" class="w-full h-full  absolute inset-0 object-cover"></div>
    <div class="relative aspect-h-1 aspect-w-1"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612476464716-431a2751e006" class="w-full h-full  absolute inset-0 object-cover"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with extra container `div`s around your image with bottom padding 100%.

You first need to extend `spacing` in your `tailwind.config.js` to include the percentage you want.

```js
module.exports = {
    theme: {
        extend: {
            spacing: {
                '1/1': '100%',
            }
        }
    },
    variants: {},
    plugins: [],
}
```

Then add the `div`s around your images:

```html
<div class="p-4">
    <div class="grid gap-4 sm:gap-8 grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 xl:grid-cols-6">
        <div class="relative pb-1/1">
            <img class="absolute w-full h-full object-cover" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41bffUhJ4xL._SL500_.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="relative pb-1/1">
            <img class="absolute w-full h-full object-cover" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41bffUhJ4xL._SL500_.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="relative pb-1/1">
            <img class="absolute w-full h-full object-cover" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612476464716-431a2751e006" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```